# How to obtain the parent path of an iterator workspace in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm selecting a folder of shapefiles in an iterator, I want to save the output in a folder within the parent folder of the shapefiles folder.

Input for iterator -- C://project/shapefile_folder

Intended output -- C://project/OtherFolder

Comment: I'm simply asking how to get the parent path of an iterator as a variable. I can then add "OtherFolder" on the the end of the variable. I edited the post to make it clearer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the model only Calculate Value tool to achieve this as shown below:

[image: Model Example]

Set up the tool as shown as this:

[image: Calculate Value tool]

```py
import os
def GetParent(ws):
  tup = os.path.split(ws)
  parent = tup[0] + "\\OtherFolder"
  return parent
```

Obviously change the final folder name.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Although, I have another question if you don't mind. This worked perfectly when I tested it out on a "workspace folder" on my desktop but when I tried it on an actual project with a more complicated path, it did not work. The output was 3 or 4 folders to back past the parent folder. Any idea what would cause that? Sorry if this is unclear what I am talking about.

Comment: After some debugging, it seems that the problem it caused by numbers being in the path. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: Without seeing an actual example of a path, can't really comment, also it's bad practise to manage data where folders or files start with numbers or have spaces and unusual characters. Sounds like you have "shot yourself in the foot" if that is the case and only now you are discovering why programmers bang on about such things and why you should never do it. ;)